# Is it possible to auto populate field based on other field selection in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, tfs-workitem

I have added below 2 custom fields in Bug work item on Azure DevOps cloud

1. Release Number (Picklist)
2. Release Environment (Picklist)

Is it possible to auto populate Release Environment when I select Release Number.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to auto populate field based on other field selection in Azure DevOps?

The answer is yes.

You could add custom rules to the Bug work item on Azure DevOps, which  allowing you to go beyond setting a default value for a field or make it required. Rules allow you to clear the value of a field, copy a value into a field, and **apply values based on dependencies between different fields' values**.

Following is my test custom rules:

[image]

Then, create other custom rules for other ReleaseNumber.

You can check the document [Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Leo let say I have a new release number and different environment associated with it, so that means I need to manually add a new rule every time.

Comment: @NaveenKumar, Could you predict the new release number? If not, you have to use the REST API to add  a new rule after you release a new number, the REST API:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/rules/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 instead of adding it manually.

Comment: Hey @Leo you mean to say I have a task in the end of release pipeline to trigger Rest api which automatically add new rule, if yes then if we have 100 releases there will be 100 rules each for 1 release.

Comment: @NaveenKumar, We can consider adding an execution condition to our task, only when your release number is updated, we will execute the rest API that adds the rule. We could add a task to compare whether the last release number is equal to the current release number, If they are not the same, then we invoke the REST API to add rule.

Comment: Thanks @Leo so every time we create a release there will be a new release number, so there will be new rule in list, is it possible to append the new release number in existing drop down.

Comment: @NaveenKumar, I am afraid we could not append the new release number in existing drop down, as you can see the condition in rules, it is **...(equals)**, so we could only set one value in the release number. If you do not want add a new rule for a release number, you could use rest api to add one more condition.

Comment: Thanks @Leo let me try one of the option.

Comment: Hey @Leo this works in some aspects but not completely, i am still figuring out the solution, if I get I will post here and thanks for help.